# Unable to get more than 100 files using Google Drive API in java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I want to retrieve files from Google Drive. I have more than 1000 files in the drive. But Drive API supports to set the page size in the range [1-1000]. So I tried to get 1000 files.

I used the following Code.

```
 FileList result = service.files().list().setPageSize(1000)
     .setFields("*")
            .execute();
 List<File> files = result.getFiles();
 System.out.println(files.size() );
```

I am able to get only 100 files from the Drive. If the pageSize is set to below 100 it is working fine.  Does anyone know why I am getting only 100 files and how to get 1000 files with single request.

Comment: is nextPageToken null?

Comment: if you are asking 
 `result.getNextPageToken()`
No, it is not null. We are getting the nextPageToken but if we use the PageToken in another request  `setPageToken(result.getNextPageToken())`
we skip only 100 files.

Comment: If next page token is not null that means there are more results,  if you are only getting 100 rows per page that means that your setPageSize(1000) isn't taking effect for some reason.

Comment: try doing set page size last I am wondering if this is a bug.

Comment: you mean 
`service.files().list()
     .setFields("*").setPageSize(1000)
            .execute();`
.No change in the result.

Comment: Issue is posted on the issue tracker here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4580&q=pageSize&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner